# @Html.ActionLink() in an if statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm learning MVC 4, and therefore using the razor engine to render my views. Please bear with me :)

I have a navigation menu that looks like this:

[image]

And I want to have an arrow that points downs towards its content when the user clicks one of the navigation menu. Here is the code:

```
<li>
     @Html.ActionLink("Business Intelligence", "Index", "Business_Intelligence")
     @if ()
     {
         <span id="triangle">
             <img src="~/Images/nav_arrow.png" />
          </span>
      }
 </li>
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Marketing Services", "MarketingServices", "Marketing")</li>
```

Now, I'm wondering what to write in the if statement. I know I need to link my arrow to an actionlink - something like this:

```
@if (@Html.ActionLink("Business Intelligence", "Index", "Business_Intelligence"))
{
  <span id="triangle">                      
     <img src="~/Images/nav_arrow.png" />
  </span>
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

PS: Does my question make sense?

Here is my view:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body>  
    <div class="WebContent"> 
    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">
           <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Business_Intelligence")">
                    <img src="~/Images/myImage-Logo.png" />
                </a>

                @if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] == "Business_Intelligence")
                {
                    <span class="triangle">
                        <img src="~/Images/nav_arrow.png" />
                    </span>
                }

            </li>                            
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Business Intelligence", "Index", "Business_Intelligence")

                @if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] == "Business_Intelligence")
                {
                    <span class="triangle">
                        <img src="~/Images/nav_arrow.png" />
                    </span>
                }

            </li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Marketing Services", "MarketingServices", "Marketing")</li>
        </ul>

    </nav>

        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        @RenderBody()
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <footer>
            <p>Footer</p>
    </footer>

    </div>

</body>
```

and my CSS:

```
 /* Images
```

-----------------------------------------------------------*/

```
.triangle{
display:block; 
text-align: center;
```

}

Comment: It is a little convoluted, what are you using the if statement for? are you trying to find if someone clicks, hovering, if the link exsists?

Comment: Correct! I'm trying to figure out if someone clicked on the menu.

Comment: ok well this can be done using the onclick attribute of the link. You can setup a function to call when the user clicks on the link such as expand something or hide another panel.

Comment: Basically, the links already exist. So, when someone clicks on either menu I would like display an image:
<span id="triangle">                      
     <img src="~/Images/nav_arrow.png" />
  </span>

Comment: Is the use of the onclick attribute the only solution available? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you effectively want to detect whether the *current page* is the one linked to by the nav item and, if so, render some additional markup on the corresponding nav item. For this, you can use `ViewContext`:

```
<li>
     @Html.ActionLink("Business Intelligence", "Index", "Business_Intelligence")
     @if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] == "Business_Intelligence")
     {
         <span id="triangle">
             <img src="~/Images/nav_arrow.png" />
          </span>
      }
 </li>
```

What this will do is check whether the current action is being executed by the `Business_Intelligence` controller and - if it is - render your additional markup below the action link.

Note that this will only render the arrow when the view is first loaded, i.e. if clicking on "Business Intelligence" loads a new page, then this solution is for you. If you need to be able to do this dynamically (e.g. clicking on "Business Intelligence" actually just renders more content via jQuery without actually refreshing the page), then Nomad101's solution is more appropriate.

If you need finer granularity than this, the collection also includes an `"action"` key.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do as I only want the image to be displayed after the click. I just implemented your solution but the image isn't showing. Do you know what could be causing it?

Comment: May be because I capitalized "Controller" - I think it should actually all be lower case. If that doesn't work, try inspecting the HTML to make sure the markup is not actually there. If not, try sticking a `@Html.Raw(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"])` somewhere in the view to double-check that there's actually a value there (should be written out in the markup where you place that Razor statement).

Comment: After I inserted @Html.Raw(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]) I was able to see Business_Intelligence displayed. That's a good sign right? However, I'm still not able to see the arrow.

Comment: Yes, that's a good sign. It means the value is there. Double-check that the casing is right in your if statement ("controller" instead of "Controller" as per my edit). If this is right and you still can't see your arrow, inspect the markup of the page directly when it loads as it sounds like it might be an issue with the markup/styles themselves rather than the Razor template.

Comment: I have never done this before - how do you inspect the markup of the page when loading?

Comment: Open the page in a browser, view the source and double check that the `<span id="triangle">` does appear within the source code. If you're still having trouble, please use pastebin or similar to share your updated view code: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: I just inspected the markup, and I couldn't find <span id="triangle">. It seems to leave a blank space for where it suppose to be.

Comment: @Oliver Can you please share your amended view code? Try http://pastebin.com. Are you sure you amended `"Controller"` to `"controller"` in the if statement?

Comment: I just posted my code using the pastebin. I gave it the same title as this post. I also changed Controller to controller.

Comment: and here is my css
/* Images
-----------------------------------------------------------*/

.triangle{
    display:block; 
    text-align: center; 
}

Comment: You need to save your pastebin entry and share the link here so we can see your code! Or just add your modified code as an update at the end of the question.

Comment: I just added my view and my css at the end of my question. 
Thanks for bearing with me

Comment: Basically, using:

    @if (@Html.Raw(ViewContext.RouteData.Values    ["controller"]).ToString() == "Business_Intelligence")

helped me see the arrow. ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] is an lHTMlString type.

Comment: is there a way to do:

 (@Html.Raw(ViewContext.RouteData.Values ["view"])

I tried it already and it seems to not work. I would like to accomplish the same exact thing

Answer (score 1):

You could use this html helper to add an html attribute of the onclick method that you want to execute when a users clicks on it.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Business Intelligence", "Index", "Business_Intelligence", null, new { onclick:"someFunc()" })
```

Some notes on this the someFunc() is a client-side java-script function. This function can easily take an argument if you would like but that is up to you. It will be executed 1 time every time the element is clicked. the null value is in place of the route-values object of the ActionLink helper, this value can control special routing values in MVC and can be very useful.

Another way would be to set the element an ID and use jquery to handle the events. something like this would work:

```
jQuery("#Link").on("click", function () { callback });
```

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you. I'm pursuing the other solution as it's what I was looking for. 
Thanks again

Comment: No problem seems I was just mistaken by what you wanted good luck.

Comment: That's my bad! I need to improve on my communication skills :)